# How to search search through a javascript object and return results ordered by some datetime

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use this functions to search through a javascript object and return results and if possible ordered by the date time field.

Searching functions:

```
function trimString(s) {
      var l=0, r=s.length -1;
      while(l < s.length && s[l] == ' ') l++;
      while(r > l && s[r] == ' ') r-=1;
      return s.substring(l, r+1);
    }

    function compareObjects(o1, o2) {
      var k = '';
      for(k in o1) if(o1[k] != o2[k]) return false;
      for(k in o2) if(o1[k] != o2[k]) return false;
      return true;
    }

    function itemExists(haystack, needle) {
      for(var i=0; i<haystack.length; i++) if(compareObjects(haystack[i], needle)) return true;
      return false;
    }

 function searchFor(toSearch) {
      var results = [];
      toSearch = trimString(toSearch); // trim it
      for(var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
        for(var key in objects[i]) {
          if(objects[i][key].indexOf(toSearch)!=-1) {
            if(!itemExists(results, objects[i])) results.push(objects[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      return results;
    }
   console.log(searchFor('This is'));
```

Javascript Object

```
{
"4dd5a49e3b0817c9a459550bc3d590fd": {
"downloadUrl": "2F4dd5a49e3b0817c9a459550bc3d590fd%2F4dd5a49e3b0817c9a459550bc3d590fd?alt=media&token=d3a400bf-3a79-44ee-af7f-f5d174167f4a",
"file_dislikes": 0,
"file_id": "4dd5a49e3b0817c9a459550bc3d590fd",
"file_likes": 0,
"file_status": "Public",
"filename": "This is my best upload style yet to date",
"upload_date": "2016-09-03T08:35:45.410Z",
"user_id": "14nWy7qG6vN7rNdquzZNhX1QvbH2",
"video_avatar": "./images/video.jpg"
},
"519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81": {
"downloadUrl": "2F519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81%2F519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81?alt=media&token=f50d9b0f-579a-4c81-b12b-35ee7e6810e2",
"file_dislikes": 0,
"file_id": "519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81",
"file_likes": 0,
"file_status": "Public",
"filename": "Another testing video",
"upload_date": "2016-09-03T04:48:04.283Z",
"user_id": "14nWy7qG6vN7rNdquzZNhX1QvbH2",
"video_avatar": "./images/video.jpg"
},
"99eed0bcc07d23f828c44c1721433c69": {
"downloadUrl": "2F99eed0bcc07d23f828c44c1721433c69%2F99eed0bcc07d23f828c44c1721433c69?alt=media&token=d9251647-567e-49df-b0da-d9525e10ed0e",
"file_dislikes": 0,
"file_id": "99eed0bcc07d23f828c44c1721433c69",
"file_likes": 0,
"file_status": "Public",
"filename": "This is Zac Brown Band - Sweet Annie ",
"upload_date": "2016-09-03T04:22:06.285Z",
"user_id": "14nWy7qG6vN7rNdquzZNhX1QvbH2",
"video_avatar": "./images/video.jpg"
 }
}
```

I use the angular service to get the object $http.

```
var objects = response.data.
```

Am trying to create a search function for my app.

Comment: Put the values in an array and sort it. Have you tried it?

Comment: So `searchFor` is already working?

Comment: The above works only with objects of this type `var objects = [
  {
    "foo" : "bar",
    "bar" : "sit"
  }]`

Comment: How do you suggest i put the values in an array?

Comment: I see. You probably want to change the loop to `for(var i in object) {` then, which will put the property values in the `results` array that you can `.sort(…)` then.